# Is create react app supposed to be used in production?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, web-deployment

I've mostly been using CRA in all of my react projects. In the past, I've only been working in development, not ever pushing to production. I just recently tried to push to production, and the size of my project (that I developed with CRA) was gigantic, like 25 GB for a pretty simple file. After doing some researching, I now know that CRA and the pre-installed node_modules is really clunky and large.

So is CRA ever really used in production, or is it better to use babel/webpack? Is it sometimes better to develop with CRA due to pre-built stuff, but use webpack / babel combo when its time to push to production?

Thanks!

Comment: CRA _uses_ Babel and Webpack, so it's not clear what distinction you're trying to draw. You certainly shouldn't be deploying the whole dependency tree, but it's unclear why you thought otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

On development or your local machine, you use an integrated server that serves your React application. But when you want to deploy to production, you only need to ship the HTML, compiled CSS, and the minified-uglified javascript generated by your [`npm run build`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#npm-run-build-or-yarn-build) command which is configured by CRA to take care of everything in most cases.

For more details, you may want to have a look at: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/

The output should be a couple of megabytes if not less as webpack will minify your assets, and do some [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) for you which should reduce the build size compared to what you have on the local development environment

After you build, the files will be written to a `dist` or a `build` folder containing the entry point of your SPA (`index.html` loading the initial React dependencies + your application build).
This folder should be served by an HTTP server, you may either have nginx or any other HTTP server doing this for you, or you may want to use a PaaS like [Vercel](https://vercel.com/) or [Netifly](https://www.netlify.com/).

---

Note that in some complex projects, the CRA can be "ejected" using the [`npm run eject`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject) command **which is a one-way operation. Once you eject, you can’t go back!**.

That would expose your build configurations and the underlying "magic" that CRA abstracts from you to allow more freedom in customization (with a cost as you would expect). This should be used wisely and it's not needed in most of the cases as I said since CRA covers the basics you would need, and they also provide [alternatives to ejecting](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/alternatives-to-ejecting/) to ensure you keep that as a last resort.